How to set doNotStrip in build.gradle.kts
My Android app project requires doNotStrip when packaging, but my project configure file is new build configuration file build.gradle.kts instead of build.gradle.  Most of the tutorials are for  build.gradle.
After I googled and ChatGPT'ed, google gives me the following answer
android {
    packagingOptions {
        doNotStrip("**/*.so") // Do not strip all *.so files
    }
}

and then I rebuild my project there are still ./app/build/intermediates/stripped_native_libs/debug/ directory in my project directory. (I have rm this dir so I'm sure this dir is newly created, so that's not working, (still stripped)). As following
/path/to/android/project_dir $ find . -name "*.so"
./app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/debug/out/lib/arm64-v8a/lib***.so
./app/build/intermediates/merged_jni_libs/debug/out/arm64-v8a/lib***.so
./app/build/intermediates/stripped_native_libs/debug/out/lib/lib***.so

Then the Android Studio give me suggestions to change packagingOptions to packaging as below
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
        jniLibs.keepDebugSymbols += "*/*/liba.so";
        jniLibs.keepDebugSymbols += "*/*/libb.so";
        jniLibs.keepDebugSymbols += "*/*/libc.so";
    }

This still doesn't work (created an ./app/build/intermediates/stripped_native_libs/debug/ directory)

How can I doNotStrip these dylibs in this brand new build system?
In fact I am not so sure if these intermediates dirs will always created despite I set packagingOptions and this works.
